# open -n with ProcessBuilder

Tags: java, macos, runtime, processbuilder

I am trying to open an application in MacOS with Java with the following command using `ProcessBuilder`:

```
ProcessBuilder process = new ProcessBuilder("open -n /Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app");
        try {
            process.start();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            logger.debug("IOException: {}", ex);
            SdkException.notify(ex.getClass().getName(), ex, getClass(), Severity.ERROR);
        }
```

It doesnt start the application, but It starts when I run with `Runtime.getRuntime().exec`

```
try{
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("open -n /Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app");
} catch (IOException ex){
    logger.debug("IOException: {}", ex);
}
```

How to make this works with `ProcessBuilder`?

Comment: I´ve provided a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, so its not a "notworking" question

Comment: @AluanHaddad, edited the word "works" to "start". Now you can understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the command arguments into separate strings. Instead of

`ProcessBuilder process = new ProcessBuilder("open -n /Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app");`

use

`ProcessBuilder process = new ProcessBuilder("open", "-n", "/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app");`

Answer (score 0):

The correct path to the Terminal in Mac is `"/System/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app"`

But you better open inside a Thread.

Like this:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        String[] params = { "open", "/System/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app" };
        try {
            new ProcessBuilder(params).start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}).start();
```